# set backgroundColor for UITextField within UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How can I programatically change the backgroundColor of an UITextField that sits in a UITableViewCell?

Setting the UITextField.backgroundColor doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I sovled it by creating my own UITextField and adding it to the UITableViewCell, but im not sure if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: created your own? What did you override?

Comment: You just add a subview to the cells contentView, like this:
[cell.contentView addSubview:yourTextView];
yourTextView is a UILabel that you initialize, set its CGRect, set its text, and set its backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

Try do it in layoutSubviews method of this cell.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: same effect, the textField is not filled (even though the frame areas (especially corners) shows the color